# Tamanho de Tela dos Smartphones

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout-responsivo

Estou produzindo um aplicativo. Gostaria de saber para quais tamanho de telas de smartphones android devo programar o layout. Os layouts que fiz não cabem em smartphones com tela de 2.7,3.2, 3.3,3.4, polegadas. Isso será muito prejudicial?

Answer (score 0):

João, a maioria dos *Smart* hoje tem a tela de 4,7 para cima são poucos abaixo disso (faça uma pesquisa nos principais *Smart* vendidos e compare as telas), imagino que se você quiser atingir todos vai acabar tendo mais trabalho do que o normal além do mais se fizer 5 *layout's* se mudar 1 id ou adicionar outro campo você terá que mudar em todos eles o cenário ideal é ter apenas 1 layout no máximo 2.

Mas se quiser ainda assim fazer segue tutorial de como fazer.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html?hl=pt-br